# Outer container is not extending with the expand script

Tags: jquery, css

So I have some function that expand and collaps based on hover and click. The function works fine on the basic test but it's not working on the site. When a user clicks on the Expand A and Expand B. The outer container expands with it as you can test it in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rexonms/pXm62/) . But when the same code is applied to the [main site](http://boston.staging.ujcweb.org/expandable-box.aspx) the outer container doesn't expand with the expanded div. Instead it has the expanded div if it's too long. What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance. Rex

P.S. I can't use the newer version of jQuery or the change the layout. That's the CMS is set up. However I can change the css properties and the javascript functions.

The jQuery script works fine on the test version: http://jsfiddle.net/rexonms/pXm62/

But it doesn't work on the site: http://boston.staging.ujcweb.org/expandable-box.aspx

Comment: Does any of the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function named `adjustLayout` in your http://boston.staging.ujcweb.org/js/globalPage.js file which sets height of `div#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_supportingElements` dynamically. Therefore your boxes can't push container.

You can try this; Change the toggle function at bottom of your http://boston.staging.ujcweb.org/local_includes/top-nav.js script to this:

```
$("a.trigger").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $container = $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_supportingElements');
    if($this.hasClass('active')) {
        $container.height($container.data('height'));
    }
    else {
        $container.data('height', $container.height()).css('height', 'auto');
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
    return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
});
```

Comment: Super... that did the trick. There are few issue with IE but, I think I can fix them. Thank you very much for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

I could not see anything on your fiddle. However, on the main site the container `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_supportingElements` had a `height` set in the element's style tag that was 676px (may be dynamically set). That's where the issue was. Either eliminating that or changing it to a `min-height` worked for child element expansion.